# How to count number of key in dictionary using for loop

Tags: python-3.x

i have created dictionary "payload" as below

```
payload=[{'id': 'Room1',   'temperature': {'metadata': {}, 'type': 'Number',
'value': ''},  
'pressure': {'metadata': {}, 'type': 'Number', 'value':
''},   'type': 'RoomTest'}]
```

I want to use for loop to count number of occurrence of attrs (keys) in dictionary.

I tried, `[ for i=0 to i<attr.size() -1:]` but no result. Some help on this will be appreciable.

Comment: This makes no sense. Enter that line into your interpreter and you'll see that the `attr` key only appears once, because a dict cannot have multiple keys that are the same.

Comment: I want to find number of occurrence of key(eg:, temperature,pressure) in dictionary , how many times it is coming

Comment: And I am telling you that the answer will *always* be 1. This is because keys must be unique. Unless what you actually have is a list of dictionaries. But that is not what your question contains. It contains a list with a single dictionary with multiple keys with the same name, which will be de-duplicated when you actually run that line in the python interpreter

Comment: yes i can find the length of payload which will be 1,but i want to find out how many times the key is occurring in list and for that i was using for loop but not able to implement it.

Comment: You've now removed the keys called `attr` and changed them to be `temperature` and `pressure` so it is unclear what you are exactly trying to count anymore. If you are simply asking how many keys in a dictionary then you can just do `len(payload[0])`.